# how to get synonyms for a word using wordnet 3.0

Tags: java, wordnet

i need to get synonyms for different words....i am using wordnet 3.0 version to do that.....what is the method or function name used to get the synonym of first sence ,all sence and WSD....

```
       ws=new JWS(dir,"3.0");
      jcn=ws.getJiangAndConrath();
      idict=ws.getDictionary();

    idict.open();
    IIndexWord idxWord = idict.getIndexWord("pine", POS.VERB);

    wlist = idxWord.getWordIDs();
    wordID = (IWordID)wlist.get(0);
    iword = idict.getWord(wordID);
    best_sense = iword.getSynset().getGloss();

    System.out.println("Sense of pine "+best_sense);
```

i have done until this right now....